# Multiple cases in switch statement with same alias

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-7.3

i'd like to know if there's an opinion how to combine 2 cases of my switch, which are almost the same, but one is for nullable value and the second is not.

```
        switch (rangeA)
        {
            case Range<int> intRangeA:
            {
                if (rangeB is Range<int> intRangeB)
                {
                    return intRangeA.ValueFrom <= intRangeB.ValueTo && intRangeA.ValueTo >= intRangeB.ValueFrom;
                }

                return false;
            }

            case Range<int?> intRangeA:
            {
                if (rangeB is Range<int?> intRangeB)
                {
                    return intRangeA.ValueFrom <= intRangeB.ValueTo && intRangeA.ValueTo >= intRangeB.ValueFrom;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The code you have [compiles and runs successfully](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FGM4TD)? What's your problem, specifically?

Comment: I dont like that i have 2 "same" cases

Comment: Oh, so you want to *combine* the two cases, not split them?

Comment: ah, yeah, my bad.. sry for wrong word

Comment: The `if` clauses are pattern matches as well. You could include them in the `case` clause instead of repeating the same check each time, by matching against the `(rangeA,rangeB)` tupple.

Comment: The two cases use two very different types - one is an int, the other is a Nullable<int>. There's no inheritance relation between them so they can't be treated as one type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It rather depends on what the data type of `rangeA` and `rangeB` are.

Assuming they're `object`, you can do something like this. It will throw an exception at runtime if you create a `Range<Something non-comparable>` then call `ContainsInclusive` on it. You can add an extra check for that if you want, but it gets a bit messy as `Nullable<T>` doesn't implement any interfaces, so you'll have to resort to reflection.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo(new Range<int>() { ValueFrom = 1, ValueTo = 10 }, new Range<int>() { ValueFrom = 0, ValueTo = 10 });
        Foo(new Range<int?>() { ValueFrom = 1, ValueTo = 10 }, new Range<int?>() { ValueFrom = 0, ValueTo = 10 });
    }
    
    private static bool Foo(object rangeA, object rangeB)
    {
        return (rangeA, rangeB) switch
        {
            (Range<int> a, Range<int> b) => b.ContainsInclusive(a),
            (Range<int?> a, Range<int?> b) => b.ContainsInclusive(a),
            _ => false,
        };
    }
}

public class Range<T> 
{
    public T ValueFrom { get; set; }
    public T ValueTo { get; set; }
    
    public bool ContainsInclusive(Range<T> other)
    {
        return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(other.ValueFrom, this.ValueTo) <= 0 &&
            Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(other.ValueTo, this.ValueFrom) >= 0; 
    }
}
```

---

If you can't use the new switch expressions in this way, you can potentially do something like:

```
private static bool Foo(object rangeA, object rangeB)
{
    return TryContainsInclusive<int>(rangeA, rangeB) ||
        TryContainsInclusive<int?>(rangeA, rangeB);
}

private static bool TryContainsInclusive<T>(object a, object b)
{
    if (a is Range<T> rangeA && b is Range<T> rangeB)
    {
        return rangeB.ContainsInclusive(rangeA);
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

---

If `rangeA` and `rangeB` can be generic types, you can get away with the simpler:

```
private static bool Foo<T>(Range<T> rangeA, Range<T> rangeB)
{
    return rangeB.ContainsInclusive(rangeA);
}
```

---

If `rangeA` and `rangeB` can be some base `Range` type, then you can do something like this. Again, this will throw at runtime if `T` isn't comparable:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo(new Range<int>() { ValueFrom = 1, ValueTo = 10 }, new Range<int>() { ValueFrom = 0, ValueTo = 10 }).Dump();
        Foo(new Range<int?>() { ValueFrom = 1, ValueTo = 10 }, new Range<int?>() { ValueFrom = 0, ValueTo = 10 }).Dump();
    }
    
    private static bool Foo(Range rangeA, Range rangeB)
    {
        return rangeB.ContainsInclusive(rangeA);
    }
}

public abstract class Range
{
    public abstract bool ContainsInclusive(Range other);
}

public class Range<T> : Range
{
    public T ValueFrom { get; set; }
    public T ValueTo { get; set; }
    
    public override bool ContainsInclusive(Range other)
    {
        if (other is Range<T> o)
        {
            return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(o.ValueFrom, this.ValueTo) <= 0 &&
                Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(o.ValueTo, this.ValueFrom) >= 0;    
        }
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: well, yeah, ur last snippet helped.. im still heading the problem we use C# 7.3 in my company, but this is cool workaround, thanks :)

Comment: @Qhori See my edit -- that's another potential way

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve the problem by having a non-abstract base class `Range`. Both `Range<int>` and `Range<int?>` are then assignment compatible to this base class.

```
class Range
{
    public object ValueFrom { get; protected set; }
    public object ValueTo { get; protected set; }
}

class Range<T> : Range
{
    public new T ValueFrom
    {
        get {
            return (T)base.ValueFrom;
        }
        set {
            base.ValueFrom = value;
        }
    }

    public new T ValueTo
    {
        get {
            return (T)base.ValueTo;
        }
        set {
            base.ValueTo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The properties of the generic class hide the properties of the base class. Their setter is protected. Therefore setting values is still type safe, because it can be done only through the generic class.

My solution then consists in testing the type of the From and To values. This also works well for nullable types. If a `nullable` is null, then `nullable is int i` yields `false`, otherwise if we have a `Range<int?>` it will assign `nullable.Value` to `i`.

This also allows you compare a `Range<int>` with a `Range<int?>`.

```
Range rangeA = new Range<int> { ValueFrom = 5, ValueTo = 12 };
Range rangeB = new Range<int?> { ValueFrom = 10, ValueTo = 18 };

if (rangeA.ValueFrom is int aFrom && rangeA.ValueTo is int aTo &&
    rangeB.ValueFrom is int bFrom && rangeB.ValueTo is int bTo) {

    return aFrom <= bTo && aTo >= bFrom;
}
return false;
```

---

A possible improvement is to have a strongly typed backing variable in the generic variant:

```
private T _valueFrom;
public new T ValueFrom
{
    get {
        return _valueFrom;
    }
    set {
        base.ValueFrom = _valueFrom = value;
    }
}
```

At least returning a value then involves no unboxing when working through the generic range.

Comment: No, cause i need a big switch, where i wanna add other data types as decimal and the best version is already added.. but thanks :)